# How to troubleshoot "Could not check origin for Phoenix.Socket transport" messages?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting a lot of "Could not check origin for Phoenix.Socket transport" messages. This seems to indicate that something is hitting my server, but with a host name in the request that doesn't match the ones I have configured. How do I debug this? How can I tell where these requests are coming from, or what is in them, or what they requested? It doesn't tell me any of this in the "Could not check origin..." message. Nor do I get any other logging that tells me more. Is there somewhere that Phoenix logs all the requests it receives so I can see what is coming in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help you: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1359

There is more descriptive error message already in master: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/socket/transport.ex#L360

```
    This happens when you are attempting a socket connection to
    a different host than the one configured in your config/
    files. For example, in development the host is configured
    to "localhost" but you may be trying to access it from
    "127.0.0.1". To fix this issue, you may either:
      1. update [url: [host: ...]] to your actual host in the
         config file for your current environment (recommended)
      2. pass the :check_origin option when configuring your
         endpoint or when configuring the transport in your
         UserSocket module, explicitly outlining which origins
         are allowed:
            check_origin: ["https://example.com",
                           "//another.com:888", "//other.com"]
```

I am not sure if there is an easy way in Phoenix to log the requests that were dropped because of origin, but I would use `:dbg` from Erlang:

```
:dbg.tracer #start tracer
:dbg.p(:all, :c) #print all matching calls
:dbg.tpl(Phoenix.Socket.Transport, :check_origin, 5, [])
#match on Module, :function, arity, (no additional options)
```

The first argument to `check_origin` is `Plug.Conn` which should include something like `{<<"origin">>, <<"http://localhost:4000">>},`.

Phoenix live reload mechanism uses websockets so when I changed `check_origin: false` in my `config/dev.exs` I am getting a lot of those.

Comment: I already have the extended error message. How do I troubleshoot when I see this? It doesn't tell me anything about where this request came from, or what they were asking for, or what host they provided in the request. Is information like that logged somewhere?

Comment: I edited the question to include information about possible way to debug the issue.